# .setActive(true) not working after second time calling it Unitiy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to Unity and I really don't know how to directly ask this question. Basicaly I am just playing around with Unitiy in general and I am trying to create script that initially has it set to active then disappear after 3 seconds but then come back as active again, can anyone explain anything specific that has to do with this problem? This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptTwo : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject theBall;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        theBall.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(BallCode());
    }

    IEnumerator BallCode() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        theBall.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Set Active: False");
        Debug.Log("Test Before");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        theBall.SetActive(true);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It looks correct to me...

Answer (score 0):

What your code should be doing is:
-activating
-waiting 3 seconds
-disabling
-waiting 3 seconds
-activating
If it is doing anything other than that it is a problem with another code you wrote. If you wanted it to continue infinitly than:

```
IEnumerator BallCode()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        theBall.SetActive(!theBall.activeInHierarchy);
        Debug.Log("Set Active: " + theBall.activeInHierarchy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script is in the gameObject you are deactivating (in this instance the ball) you should move it to another gameObject.

All Unity Monobehaviour methods and by extent coroutines, are halted/stopped when the gameObject is deactivated.